# Integral properties

Tags: calculus, integration

**Hi, someone knows how make the procedure to reach, this, I dont undestand how integration limits are change **

[image: Solution for integral]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As you can see, area from $x$ to $y$ is area from $0$ to $y$ $-$ area from $0$ to $x$

Answer (score 0):

The sum of two integrals over adjacent intervals is,

$$\int_{0}^{x}g(t)\,dt+\int_{x}^{y}g(t)\,dt=\int_{0}^{y}g(t)\,dt.$$

Now subtract $\int_{0}^{x}g(t)\,dt$ from both sides. *qed*

Answer (score 0):

By definition of definite integration, if there exists a function, $G(x)$, derivable on the interval $x\in[a,b]$ then:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d} G(x)}{\mathrm {d} x} = g(x) \implies \int_a^b g(x) \;\mathrm{d}x = G(b)-G(a)$$

So if we take the identity (since $G(\color{red}{b})-G(\color{red}{b})=0$):
$$G(\color{blue}{c}) - G(\color{green}{a}) = G(\color{blue}{c})-G(\color{red}{b})+G(\color{red}{b})-G(\color{green}{a})$$

By substitution:
$$\therefore \int_{\color{green}{a}}^{\color{blue}{c}} g(x)\;\mathrm{d}x  = \int_{\color{red}{b}}^{\color{blue}{c}} g(x)\;\mathrm{d}x + \int_{\color{green}{a}}^{\color{red}{b}} g(x)\;\mathrm{d}x $$

That's how the interval limits work.